# Javascript return undefined for an internal function

Tags: javascript

I am doing an easy leetcode questions where we add one to a number whose digits are stored in an array. My logic works well but the returned value is undefined. Console gives the correct answer. Why? And how do I fix it?

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits)
    
    function addNumber(index, value, digitsArr) {
        let sum = digitsArr[index] + value    
        if(sum > 9) {
            let onesDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(1))
            digitsArr[index] = onesDigit
            let twosDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(0))
            addNumber(index-1, twosDigit, digitsArr)
        } else {
          digitsArr[index] = sum
          console.log(digitsArr)
          return digitsArr
        }
    }
};

console.log(plusOne([1,2,9]))
```

Comment: `plusOne` is not returning anything. Try `return addNumber(...):`

Comment: Tried it using default parameters but didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** `return` the value of function `addNumber`, If you won't return something from a function then JS will return `undefined` implicitely

```
  return addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits);
```

**2)** You have to return value from the `addNumber` function in every case. There are one of the two things that you could do

- `return digitsArr` from function `addNumber` not only from `else` part.
- return `addNumber(index - 1, twosDigit, digitsArr);` from the `if` and return `digitsArr` from the `else`.

> Main part is to return something from the function that totally depends on what exactly you want to do with your code.

```js
var plusOne = function(digits) {
  return addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits);

  function addNumber(index, value, digitsArr) {
    let sum = digitsArr[index] + value;
    if (sum > 9) {
      let onesDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(1));
      digitsArr[index] = onesDigit;
      let twosDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(0));
      addNumber(index - 1, twosDigit, digitsArr);
    } else {
      digitsArr[index] = sum;
    }
    return digitsArr;
  }
};

console.log(plusOne([1, 2, 9]));
```

Answer (score 2):

plusOne does not return anything neither addNumber(index-1, twosDigit, digitsArr)

try:

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
    return addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits)
    
    function addNumber(index, value, digitsArr) {
        let sum = digitsArr[index] + value    
        if(sum > 9) {
            let onesDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(1))
            digitsArr[index] = onesDigit
            let twosDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(0))
            return addNumber(index-1, twosDigit, digitsArr)
        } else {
          digitsArr[index] = sum
          console.log(digitsArr)
          return digitsArr
        }
    }
};

console.log(plusOne([1,2,9]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function `plusOne` which inturn calls the internal function `addNumber`. It is not returnng any value. So instead of just calling `addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits)` you have to return that value like `return addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits)`. Because your parent function is expection the result of the execution. So you have to dend it back with a `return` statement.

Also inside `addNumber` function when the sume is greater that 9 rether than calling `addNumber(index - 1, twosDigit, digitsArr)` you have to return the result of that execution with `return addNumber(index - 1, twosDigit, digitsArr)`. Just like the previous case, here also its executor is expecting the response back from the function.

```js
var plusOne = function (digits) {
    return addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits);

    function addNumber(index, value, digitsArr) {
        let sum = digitsArr[index] + value;
        if (sum > 9) {
            let onesDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(1));
            digitsArr[index] = onesDigit;
            let twosDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(0));
            return addNumber(index - 1, twosDigit, digitsArr);
        } else {
            digitsArr[index] = sum;
            return digitsArr;
        }
    }
};

console.log(plusOne([1, 2, 9]));
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript a function that lacks an explicit return statement will return undefined. You are calling a function plusOne which in turn is calling(not returning) addNumber but both the functions do not explicitly return anything, try returning addNumber in both cases.

```
var plusOne = function (digits) {
    return addNumber(digits.length - 1, 1, digits);

    function addNumber(index, value, digitsArr) {
        let sum = digitsArr[index] + value;
        if (sum > 9) {
            let onesDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(1));
            digitsArr[index] = onesDigit;
            let twosDigit = parseInt(sum.toString().charAt(0));
            return addNumber(index - 1, twosDigit, digitsArr);
        } else {
            digitsArr[index] = sum;
            return digitsArr;
        }
    }
};

console.log(plusOne([1, 2, 9]));
```